# Complex Analysis Continuation

Tags: complex-analysis

Please help on the following complex analysis problem. I believe it can be done using a Laurent series.

Basically proving Schwarz's reflection principle.

> Let $f(z)$ be analytic in unit circle and real and continuous on the unit circle. Show that $\bar{f(z)} = f\left( \frac 1 {\bar z}\right)$ is the continuation of $f(z)$ outside the unit circle. How does this relate to Schwars's principle?

Answer (score 0):

Using a linear fractional transformation, you can reduce this to the standard Schwarz reflection principle for the upper half plane.

Comment: I understand bilinear transformations but can you elaborate on how I can implement this method?

Comment: Look at $f$ composed with the LFT that takes the unit circle to the real line. You can apply the standard reflection principle to extend this function to the lower half plane. Then transforming it back to the unit circle gives your desired extension.